# В чем моя ошибка?

Tags: javascript

Если элементы x расположены в порядке возрастания, возвращает true, иначе false

```js
function sortA(x) {

  return x.sort((a, b) => a > b) ? true : false

}

console.log(sortA([1, 15, 8]))
```

Comment: это как преобразовать?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods#sortirovka-metod-sort-fn

Comment: А здесь в чем ошибка сказано что если правилно то true если нет false?нет ли?

Comment: вкоде где ошибка всегда дает true?

Comment: в моем примере должень возврашать false ,но что сделать?

Comment: Вам же дали ссылку на документацию. А там написано, что функция компарер должна возвращать **число**.

Comment: тут может быть как `-1`, так и `0` или `1`, причем тут `true` ? Вы документации читаете или сами себе придумываете?

Comment: function compareNumeric(a, b) {
  if (a > b) return 1;
  if (a < b) return -1;
}

Answer (score 1):

Пример

```js
var sortA = x => x.every((a,b,c) => !b || c[b-1] <= a);
console.log(sortA([1, 15, 8, -15]));
console.log(sortA([-5, 1, 2, 8]));
console.log(sortA([3, 0, 5]));
```

Comment: Ага, щас. `[3, 0, 5]` - ответ `false`, а Ваша функция вернёт `true`

Comment: Уберите эту неоптимальную (и неправильную) проверку на выход за границы массива. Просто сразу задайте верный диапазон для цикла

Comment: @Kir_Antipov  вы правы, обновил

Comment: Теперь как надо работает) Лишняя проверка все же осталась, но красота решения в функциональном стиле ее оправдывает хД

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, `var sortA = x => !x.some((a,b,c) => a > c[b+1]);`

Answer (score 1):

Функция [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) возвращает **отсортированный массив**, поэтому, в части

```
x.sort((a, b) => a > b) ?
```

всегда будет `true`.

Следовательно и результат функции всегда будет `true`.

---

Если нужно только проверить порядок элементов, только его и надо проверять, а не просто сортировать массив.